# Using a closure to encapsulate state for React components

Tags: reactjs

When passing data between two elements that are very far away from each other in the hierarchy of components, passing data through props can be tedious. In these use cases I've resorted to using Redux just because it is less to keep track of when there is a large amount of components.

What I've done in one little project is to use a closure to encapsulate state and export that variable and consume it elsewhere. I feel this is a an antipattern but it does work.

The way it works is by declaring some variable that is going to be modified within a component. This same variable is the imported from elsewhere and consumed from elsewhere.

Here is a small sample with what I am doing (just pretend there is a large component hierarchy): https://codesandbox.io/s/2R9RvYkN1

So my questions are: is there a better way to achieve the same results? Should we use a Flux implementation for these use cases? Is it ok to just pass props around through a large hierarchy of components?

Comment: You should probably share the code pattern within the SO post with a concrete example.

Comment: If you were using Redux, there would be no need to set the selected color.  `ColorSelector` would dispatch an action which would update the state and the selected color would be updated automatically without the user needing to click a button.

Answer (score 0):

As you stated yourself, redux solves this problem by providing an "App state" that's global to your app, which allows you to connect any component you want to that state.

Your "closure" is merely a poor-man's Redux, it's also a global state, only it lacks any of the features provided by Redux(unless you write them specifically).

let's CompA needs to re-render based on a click event on CompB, how do you do that automatically with a closure? you'd have to add listeners, check if a relevant state was changed and then re-render.

all these things are done for free by Redux, so I don't see any added benefit(except for not using redux, which can be a benefit in it's own).

If it's that important not to use redux, this can be "fine", yet very dangerous and I'd say it won't scale well.